# Difference of std::move and std::ref in this case

Tags: c++11

I found myself getting more confused when I learned more about the rvalue reference and std::move introduced in C++11.

Look at this example:

I have function template that enqueue the function object:

```
template<typename F, typename... Args>
void push(F && f, Args&&... args){
  std::function<int(int)> func = f;
  //Here function_queue is a object of queue<std::function<int(int)>>
  function_queue.push(std::move(f));
}
```

I have this function

```
int foo(int i){return i;}
```

I can call the push in three ways:

```
1. push(foo)
2. push(std::move(foo))
3. push(std::ref(foo))
```

Looks all of them work well.
But what's the difference between them. In which scenario should I use one of them over the others.

Comment: You could also forward `f` into the queue `push(std::forward<F&&>(f))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this circumstance there is no difference between 1 and 2 since what you are actually passing into the function is a good old fashioned function pointer.  Moving a pointer is the same as copying it, so they all do the same thing.

However, say you have a function object that has a some heavy duty state like this ...

```
struct dude {
    std::vector<int> data;

    int operator()(int) const { return 0; }
}

dude whoa{5,6,7,8,9};

push(whoa); // copies the dude's data
push(std::move(whoa)); // moves the dude's data!
```

Then the move becomes meaningful, and faster.  Also, use either `std::forward` or `static_cast` instead of the `std::move` inside of push, since you don't know if what you got is actually an rvalue reference.

```
  function_queue.push(std::forward<F &&>(f));
```

Personally, I prefer just directly static_casting instead of using std::forward, since the debugger will step into std::forward which I found quite annoying.  So, this is also an option ...

```
  function_queue.push(static_cast<F &&>(f));
```

Finally, as far as the `std::ref` goes, that is wrapping the function object in a `std::reference_wrapper` that only holds a reference to the function object.  That means you are NOT passing ownership of the object to the std::function inside of the push, and if the object goes out of scope you have a dangling reference, which is no good.  However, if you know for certain that the referenced function object will always exist, then this avoids copy AND move for the function object.  For example ...

```
{
    dude whoa{1,2,3,4};
    push(std::ref(whoa));
}
// whoa is out of scope here, and the std::function 
// which grabbed the std::reference_wrapper object holds a dangling reference!
```